# AADSTS700016: GCP & Azure & React URL Login is not reaching the correct Azure AD Tenant despite using correct and same App Registration Config

Tags: reactjs, azure, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory

Thanks for reading, I am having a problem with my react application and authentication with passport-js. but I ran into a problem with code AADSTS700016. This error says that tenant directory is not correct, which definitely is not (I can see it correctly where I registered my app on Azure portal. For some reason why I use my regular gcp app engine URL it works but not the custom one. Why is this config breaking?

I have deployed Node JS App on Google App Engine successfully however after deployment and login with the custom url leads to an error. React Code is below.

```
    exports.creds = {
  // Required
  identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration', 
  // or equivalently: 
  //
  // or you can use the common endpoint
  // 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
  // To use the common endpoint, you have to either turn `validateIssuer` off, or provide the `issuer` value.

  // Required, the client ID of your app in AAD  
        
  clientID: “xxxx",

  // Required if `responseType` is 'code', 'id_token code' or 'code id_token'. 
  // If app key contains '\', replace it with '\\'.
 
  clientSecret:”xxxx",

  // Required, must be 'code', 'code id_token', 'id_token code' or 'id_token'
  // If you want to get access_token, you must use 'code', 'code id_token' or 'id_token code' 
  responseType: 'code', 

  // Required
  responseMode: 'form_post', 

  // Required, the reply URL registered in AAD for your app
//redirectUrl: 'test.com/auth/openid/return',
```

[image: Error Picture]

Answer (score 0):

See whether the users are restricted to login to the app (whether it needs users to be explicitly given permission within the app in Azure).